# Form method stops Task with cancellation token and waits for task to complete. Stop Method never yields and Task does not stop

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, deadlock

I have a Service Class that Starts and Stops a task that is intended to run in the background behind a forms app.

When stopping the monitor:
Once the `Stop()` method is called, no breakpoints are hit on the Monitor Task and `IsStarted` never becomes false' and is stuck in an infinite loop.

What is wrong with this? Why does the Monitor Task seeming stop running? How do I fix this?

```cs
        private volatile bool IsStarted = false;

        public void Start(PartList partList, UnioServiceSettings settings, Action<string, string, string> createSummaryFile)
        {
            _Settings = settings;
            _PartList = partList;
            _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            Task.Run(async() => await Monitor(_cts.Token));  //no difference:.ConfigureAwait(false);
            _ProgressMessage?.Report("Monitor Started...");
            IsStarted = true;
        }
            
        public async Task<bool> Stop()
        {
            if (IsStarted)
            {
                _ProgressMessage?.Report("Stopping Monitor...");
                _cts.Cancel();
                while (IsStarted) //this loop runs forever
                {
                    await Task.Delay(1000);  //.ConfigureAwait(false);? no difference
                }
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                _ProgressMessage?.Report("Cannot stop Monitor. It has not been started.");
                return false;
            }
        }

        private async Task Monitor(CancellationToken token)
        {
            while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                 //do stuff
                 await Task.Delay(_Settings.DelayMs,token).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
            IsStarted = false;
            return;
        }
```

Comment: Where is the `IsStarted` defined? Is it defined as a `volatile` field?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias `IsStarted` is a private property in the Service class. Marking as volatile didn't change anything. I added it to my code above

Comment: As a side note, a [`Monitor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.monitor) class exists in the `System.Threading` namespace, so giving the name `Monitor` to your method might make your life difficult in case you want to interact with the `Monitor` class. It might also create confusion to future maintainers. My suggestion would be to name it something different, like `MonitorAsync`.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Monitor is NOT the real name. Just an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a race condition here:

```
Task.Run(async() => await Monitor(_cts.Token));
_ProgressMessage?.Report("Monitor Started...");
IsStarted = true;
```

It is possible that the `Task` created by the `Task.Run` method will complete on another thread before the current thread calls `IsStarted = true;`. So eventually the `IsStarted` will settle at the value `true` without a `Task` running. To solve this problem you could transfer the responsibility of mutating the `IsStarted` field exclusively to the `Monitor` method itself:

```
private async Task Monitor(CancellationToken token)
{
    IsStarted = true;
    try
    {
        _ProgressMessage?.Report("Monitor Started...");
        while (true)
        {
            token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            //do stuff
            await Task.Delay(_Settings.DelayMs,token).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        IsStarted = false;
    }
}
```

I don't know if this race condition is the cause of your problem though.

---

**Update:** Here is another approach at implementing your service, where the `bool IsStarted` field has been replaced with a `Task _monitorTask` field. This implementation assumes that a caller will not invoke the methods `Start` and `Stop` concurrently. It actually enforces the no-concurrency policy, with the help of a [`SemaphoreSlim(1, 1)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim).

```
private readonly SemaphoreSlim _semaphore = new(1, 1);
private CancellationTokenSource _cts;
private Task _monitorTask;
private IProgress<string> _progressMessage;

public void Start()
{
    if (!_semaphore.Wait(0)) throw new InvalidOperationException("Concurrency!");
    try
    {
        if (_monitorTask != null && !_monitorTask.IsCompleted)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The Monitor is already running!");
        _progressMessage?.Report("Starting Monitor...");
        _cts = new();
        CancellationToken token = _cts.Token;
        _monitorTask = Task.Run(() => MonitorAsync(token), token);
    }
    finally { _semaphore.Release(); }
}

public async Task<bool> Stop()
{
    if (!_semaphore.Wait(0)) throw new InvalidOperationException("Concurrency!");
    try
    {
        if (_monitorTask == null)
        {
            _progressMessage?.Report("Monitor has not been started.");
            return false;
        }
        else if (_monitorTask.IsCompleted)
        {
            _progressMessage?.Report("Monitor is already stopped.");
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            _progressMessage?.Report("Stopping Monitor...");
            _cts?.Cancel();
            try { await _monitorTask; } catch { } // Ignore exceptions here
            _cts?.Dispose(); _cts = null;
            return true;
        }
    }
    finally { _semaphore.Release(); }
}

private async Task MonitorAsync(CancellationToken token)
{
    try
    {
        _progressMessage?.Report("Monitor started.");
        while (true)
        {
            // Do stuff
            await Task.Delay(1000, token);
        }
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException) when (token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        _progressMessage?.Report("Monitor stopped.");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _progressMessage?.Report($"Monitor failed: {ex.Message}");
    }
}
```

Notice that the `_cts.Token` is stored in a local variable inside the `Start` method, in order to prevent a possible race condition. The `Task.Run` action is invoked on another thread, most probably after the completion of the `Start` method. We don't want this action to interact with the `_cts` field, which must be handled from concurrency-protected regions only.

Comment: I think putting the `Try/Finally` fixed it with setting `IsStarted` in finally. Does cancelling a token throw an exception? Something is going on that I don't understand. I have code right after the while loop that NEVER get executed `_ProgressMessage?.Report("Monitor Stopped.");`

Comment: @GisMofx yes, the `await Task.Delay` throws an exception when the token is canceled. That's why it is generally preferable to avoid checking the `token.IsCancellationRequested`, and just call `token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` at strategic points instead. This way you'll have consistent cancellation behavior (exception always instead of exception sometimes).

Comment: Thanks! That's the one that throwing exception. Makes sense. Can you provide a short example here of using `ThrowIfCancellationRequested()`?

Comment: @GisMofx btw tracking the state of a `Task` with flags like the `IsStarted` field is not the most robust way of doing things, because it increases the risk of race conditions. If I was in your shoes I would keep the `Task` itself in a private field, which would allow me to know if it's running or not by querying its `IsCompleted` property. It would also allow me to `await` the `Task`, instead of doing loops until it completes.

Comment: I was wondering what that mechanism looks like instead of a boolean like you say. Would you mind adding an example?  Does the start method look the same? Does the `Start` method look the same?

Comment: @GisMofx I could add an example, but first I would like to know if it's possible that the `Start` and the `Stop` methods can be called concurrently, or some mechanism exists that prevents concurrent invocations of the two methods. If concurrency is possible, it's a bit more tricky to do it correctly.

Comment: They are called from buttons. So once Start button is clicked, the button is disabled. Same goes for stop button, once clicked both buttons are disabled until task is stopped and then start button is enabled.

Comment: @GisMofx I updated the answer with an example without the `IsStarted` flag.